# eigenvalue error

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two symmetric matrices of the same size, and let $\alpha_k$ and $\beta_k$ be the $k$th largest eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ respectively.  What can we say about $|\beta_k - \alpha_k|$ in terms of $||B - A||_2$?  To be clearer, I want the tightest possible upper bound on $|\beta_k - \alpha_k|$ using only the stated assumptions, and computed as a function of $||B - A||_2$.

Comment: Can you then at least say why you want this? Maybe there is a different approach.

Comment: Jonas T: I want this because I am doing a math research and the question is too noob for mathoverflow.  I've been looking at theorems like Weyl and like Bauer-Fike and I'm wondering if there is a theorem that very specifically addresses my question.  If not then I can piece it together from other theorems I can find on the google.

Comment: If you are subtly asking whether this is homework then the answer is no.

Comment: No, I'm not wondering if it is homework or not, your question just is not very "well-posed" in a mathematical sense.

Comment: I have edited the question in response to the comment about it not being very "well-posed" in a mathematical sense.

Comment: If you take into account that two different matrices related only by a similarity transformation can have the same eigenvalues... I'm not convinced of the usefulness of such a bound. Certainly, one can use a transformation matrix with large condition number, and that might worsen any upper bound expression anyone cares to construct.

Comment: Which matrix norm do you mean by $\|B-A\|_2$?

Comment: @Willie: is there a different interpretation of that apart from it being the Hölder 2-norm? (I'm genuinely curious and feeling especially dense today...)

Comment: @Willie Wong: In this case because the matrix is symmetric I mean the largest absolute value of eigenvalues of B-A.  This is the induced Euclidean norm which is the spectral norm for square matrices.

Comment: @J.M. Well, it could also technically be the Frobenius 2 norm (the squared entry-wise norm), which is different from the spectral norm; they are all roughly equivalent, but since the OP asked about "tightest possible bounds", it is useful to know that norm he particularly has in mind.

Comment: @Willie: FWIW, $\|\cdot\|_F$ is reserved for the Frobenius norm in the stuff I've seen (i.e., I've never seen $\|\cdot\|_2$ be used for anything other than the spectral norm in the matrix context).

Comment: @J.M. $\|\cdot\|_p$ is often used in the context of operator theory/functional analysis for the Schatten $p$-norm, where the $p = 2$ case is the Frobenius norm and $p = \infty$ case is the spectral norm, hence the confusion. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm

Comment: @Willie: Aha, so we really are in different fields of study. :D Sorry about that, I can only say that I was assuming the conventions they use in numerical linear algebra, which was why I was wondering how it could have been anything other than the spectral norm. Thanks for the enlightenment!

Comment: The |difference of eigenvalues| can be bounded by the two norm of A-B.  See (13) in https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/#more-3341

Answer (score 3):

I am slightly unsure about the following approach, so you should double check if that is correct. I'll use $\|\cdot\|_2$ to denote the spectral norm as above, and $\|\cdot \|_F$ for the Frobenius norm.

It is well known that for $n\times n$ matrices,  $\|\cdot \|_F \leq \sqrt{n} \|\cdot\|_2$ is sharp from just the definition of the norms. Now, I claim that

$$ |\beta_k - \alpha_k| \leq \|B - A\|_F $$

is also sharp. Fix the eigenvalues $\beta_k$ and $\alpha_k$. Consider orthogonal transformations of the symmetric matrix $B$ by $Q$. It suffices to compute the minimum

$$ \inf_{Q\in O(n)} \| QBQ^T - A\|_F $$

But using the definition of the Frobenius norm as an inner product, you see that

$$ \| QBQ^T - A\|_F^2 = \mathop{Tr}\left[ (QBQ^T - A)(QBQ^T - A) \right] = \|B\|_F^2 + \|A\|_F^2 - 2 A\cdot_F (QBQ^T)$$

It's an exercise to see that $A\cdot_F (QBQ^T)$ is maximized when all the $k$th eigenspace of $A$ lines up with that of $QBQ^T$ (some sort of Cauchy-Schwarz plus re-arrangement inequality). When the eigen-spaces line up, you have that

$$ \| QBQ^T - A\|_F^2 = \sum_{k = 1}^n |\beta_k - \alpha_k|^2 $$

and so the desired inequality holds, and is attained with the eigenvalues only differ in one position.

---

Unfortunately, the composition of these two inequalities is not automatically sharp, since the bound of $|\beta_k-\alpha_k|$ by $\|B-A\|_F$ is only sharp with $B-A$ has rank 1, while the first bound can be sharpened $\|C\|_F \leq \sqrt{\mathop{rank}(C)} \|C\|_2$. But it is clear that the most general sharp bound should be

$$ |\beta_k-\alpha_k| \leq s\|B-A\|_2$$

with $1 \leq s \leq \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: So far, it looks sound, but I'm too tired to try and "break" your bounds... maybe after a good night's rest. P.S. Usually $Q$ is used for denoting orthogonal matrices since $O$ is too easily confused with zero. A mere quibble, of course. :)

Comment: @J.M. fixed to your liking. :)

Comment: I upvoted it before commenting, just so you know. ;)

Comment: No, seriously, that was a valid point. I've by habit written $O$ for orthogonal matrices, but have quite often seen textbooks where $Q$ is used. I never really paid thought to why they used $Q$ instead of $O$, and now I know.

Answer (score 0):

I am too untrusted to add a comment so i'm spamming this as an answer.

J.M: I think you are considering the converse of the question.  If you have two very different-looking matrices it is possible that they have the same spectrum.  But if you have two similar-looking matrices, then is it possible that their spectra can be very different?

Comment: The theorem I remember is "tiny perturbations in matrix entries correspond to tiny perturbations in eigenvalues" for *symmetric* matrices (for unsymmetric matrices, even a tiny perturbation can cause a matrix to be defective); but since I'm far away from my books, I can't give the rigorous formulation.

Comment: @minel: Instead of spamming the site with answers that should be comments, please earn the reputation needed for commenting by provinding useful answers.

Comment: @Rasmus: That's a little harsh.

Comment: @Noah Snyder: To my defense led me please notice that this is my third comment on an answer of this kind by minel. The others were at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13318/i-am-so-confused/13320#13320 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13308/analytical-expression-to-find-the-shortest-distance-between-two-ellipses/13310#13310 . That's we the comment above lacks something like a kind first sentence. I don't think the workaround of posting answers instead of comments should be accepted just because the poster doesn't have enough rep to post comments.

Comment: @minel: Please excuse if my comment above appears harsh to you. I really meant to submit the sober information in it.

Comment: Fair enough, three comments in you'd hope someone would have gotten an upvote or two if they were adding value.

Comment: @Noah: I'm afraid, I cannot parse your latest comment.

Comment: I meant I now understand your impatience, if the first two comments had added value then they would have gotten upvoted and we wouldn't be in this situation with the third one.