# Analytical Expression to find the Shortest Distance between Two Ellipses?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

If I have the Keplerian elements for two orbits, how do I compute the shortest distance between these two orbits in 3D space? Is there any analytical expression to compute that?

Comment: This is already quite difficult in 2D: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_of_closest_approach_of_ellipses_and_ellipsoids .  It may not be solved in 3D. It is of course not difficult to solve numerically.